# Amending a custom context menu command for moving files to a custom Dropbox folder

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-registry, dropbox, context-menu

How do I change this context menu command to open a single explorer window even if multiple files have been selected?

The code below effectively moves the files selected to a custom folder in Dropbox. However, if multiple files are selected then multiple explorer windows are opened.

I know it can be improved upon, for example, to have better handling of multiple files and to work without using `cmd` so there isn't a flash of a command prompt when executed - amendments are welcome.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Move to Dropbox Folder\command]
@="cmd /k \"MOVE \"%1\" \"%%USERPROFILE%%\\Dropbox\\Music\\New Music\" & explorer \"%%USERPROFILE%%\\Dropbox\\Music\\New Music\"\" & exit"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Move to Dropbox Folder]
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Dropbox\\Client\\Dropbox.exe"
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025678/copy-current-file-selection-using-batch-command

Comment: Suggest using [Context Menu Launcher](https://github.com/zenden2k/context-menu-launcher/releases/tag/1.0) - see detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247806/pipe-multiple-files-into-a-single-batch-file-using-explorer-highlight/41463293#41463293).

Answer (score 0):

For creating a custom context menu command to move audio files to a specific Dropbox folder, create the following files.

- `dropbox.reg` (run this)

  ```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\audio\Shell\Dropbox]
  @="Move to Dropbox Folder"
  "Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Dropbox\\Client\\Dropbox.exe"

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\audio\Shell\Dropbox\command]
  @="C:\\Portable Apps\\Registry Hacks\\dropbox.bat \"%1\""
  ```
- And then `dropbox.bat` (put this at `C:\Portable Apps\Registry Hacks`)

  ```
  @echo off
  setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

  if "%~1"=="" exit /b

  set "targetFolder=%USERPROFILE%\Dropbox\Music\New Music"
  for %%a in (%*) do move "%%~fa" "%targetFolder%"
  ```